# What are the steps to reverse engineering a Shockwave .DCR file?

Tags: binary-analysis, decompilation, virtual-machines, binary-diagnosis

I have been fascinated by reverse engineering after making several emulators and  finding the [pret](https://github.com/pret) community. I love the idea behind decompiling old games and recreating source code that recompiles into a matching file.

I recently found an old game that was hosted by Cartoon Network that I must have played around ~2001. I downloaded the source file and it is 514 Kb file with a `.dcr` extension.

If this is anything like any other computer program, this file should store all of the games logic, images/sound, etc. that is interpreted by the Adobe Shockwave VM.

Is it a feasible task to reverse engineer and extract data/code from a compiled `.dcr` file, or is this technology too outdated and proprietary to try and reverse engineer and test? Apparently the `.dcr` file is generated by the "Director" application. Does this mean that if I wanted to RE this game, I would have to find the exact Director version they used when creating the game so it compiles into the same bytecode? Is this too complex of a project for a single person?

Comment: What could you do? I have a demo game from my childhood and I thought maybe I could scramble the codes so I can translate it to the full version. Do you think this is possible?

Comment: @FlashandDashDemo So over 4 years have passed since I posted this question. Recently I researched options again and I discovered that recently someone developed: https://github.com/ProjectorRays/ProjectorRays

You can use this to decompile DCR files and also convert them into workable DIR files that can be opened with director. I used this program and it perfectly decompiled the game I was originally posting about. Good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a lot to Google on the topic, so take some time to do that and learn about what the *.dcr format is. A great initial point of reference for you is [this post on the ZenHAX forum](https://zenhax.com/viewtopic.php?t=252), where a script or two have been created for use with their program, [QuickBMS](http://aluigi.altervista.org/quickbms.htm). That won't teach you how to reverse the format, but if you spend some time reading [what QuickBMS scripts are comprised of](https://www.vg-resource.com/thread-28180.html), you'll end up travelling down the path of reversing file formats using archives themselves as the sample.

I actually worked on reversing a Director application not too terribly long ago. I made notes and documented what I'd found at the time [here](https://www.betaarchive.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=428167#p428167) and [here](https://www.betaarchive.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=428500#p428500), so those may be useful for ancillary points in regards to your studying.

Finally, you'd probably be best suited to inquire around both the [ZenHAX](https://zenhax.com/) and [XeNTaX](http://forum.xentax.com/) forums, since they both primarily focus on reversing file formats. That should all get you started quite nicely in the direction you're interested in heading. =)

Comment: more links: https://github.com/eriksoe/Schockabsorber https://github.com/Brian151/OpenShockwave/ http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/Lingo_bytecode